# Django session cookie lost because of multiple concurrent requests

Tags: python, django, session, cookies

I'm building an application in which the client pings the server every now and then (let's not get into why). When the server handles these requests, it checks whether the client is logged in or not using request.user.is_authenticated()

It looks something like this:

```
def handle_ping_request(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
       # Do something...
    else:
       # Do Something else...
```

I've noticed that sometimes the server receives a log-in request immediately followed by a ping request (from the same user). The client is then successfully logged-in, the response returns with a new session ID (of the logged in user) and (I guess that) the old session-ID (of the anonymous user) is removed. When the ping request is processed, its request contains the old session-ID. Thus the ping request returns with a third session ID and on the next request the client makes, the client is no longer logged in.

My log-in code looks something like:

```
if not request.user.is_authenticated():
    user = auth.authenticate(...credentials...)

    if user and user.is_active:
        auth.login(request, user)
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to avoid this problem? Preferably without involving the client.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably too messy to handle this on the server because you'll have to create some kind of a semaphore system that will also try to guess if any ping is currently from a client that is also being authenticated.  My suggestion would be simply to change the client code not to ping while it's waiting for a response to its login request.

Comment: If the client pings just before it logs-in, the log-in request could get to the server before the ping request. That means that the client will also have to wait for all ping requests to finish before sending a log-in request. That also seems like a semaphore mechanism :)

Comment: That's true, but at least the client only has one precisely identifiable server, whereas the server would have to find the client's several "needle" sessions in the overall haystack of all the current sessions, which seems like a bigger task.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an alternative to the standard [contrib.auth.login method](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py#L65) that keeps the same session id, rather than generating a new one, either by using a custom authentication backend that doesn't generate a new key, or by creating a custom session backend that overrides the [cycle_key() method in contrib.sessions.base](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py#L265) to reuse the same key.

BUT: think about what you might be opening yourself up to by reusing the same session key - depending on where this system is in use, you'd be making yourself more open to session hijacking (ie: there's only one session id to sniff), as well as potentially issues where caches may return the unauth page content instead of the auth page content because the sessionid is technically the same and the cache can't tell the difference between the two situations, etc, etc, etc.

In short: there's a reason it's built to work, by default, the way it does.